# IPBWI error on IPB

Tags: php

got this error, i'm really confused why, everything is new, i haven't touched the code, and this is for Invision Power Board.

**Warning**: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in **C:\xampp\htdocs\f\ipbwi\lib\member.inc.php** on line **1262**

line **1262** code: `$online = implode($separator,$online);`

Comment: what value are there in `$separator,$online`? Can you show us.

Comment: Betting money on the fact that `$online` is not an array. This is probably due to a service that is no longer available, like a plugin that made AJAX calls or something. Just a guess, though. It's extremely hard to tell with this very limited question.

Comment: public function listOnlineMembers($detailed = false, $formatted = false, $show_anon = false, $order_by = 'running_time', $order = 'DESC', $separator = ', ')